# Socket.io call across server.js and api

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket.io emits from two files: `server.js` and `/routes/api.game.js`.

My `server.js`:

```
...
const server = require('./middleware/socket').server;
const io = require('./middleware/socket').io;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on("startGame", () => {
    io.emit('gameStarted')
  });
});
```

**This emit works correclty**

My `/middleware/socket.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const http = require('http');
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require('path');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const games = require("../routes/api/games");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use("/api/games", games);
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("IT'S WORKING!")
})

module.exports = { io: io, app: app, server: server };
```

And my `/routes/api/game.js`:

```
const server = require('../../middleware/socket').server;
const io = require('../../middleware/socket').io;

router.get("/start/:handle", (req, res) => {
  io.emit('nextquestion')
})

module.exports = router;
```

But here emit shows error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined**.

How can I call emit from `game.js` file?

Comment: Maby is something wrong with your path to 'io'. Could you preent screen your structure of your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that you have a circular dependency:

- `socket.js` requires `game.js`
- `game.js` requires `socket.js` which is not initialized yet, so the object equals empty object

As a best practice, I would recommend to never initialize objects outside of a function because it's like applying a side effect when you call require. 
`game.js` only needs `socket.io` so if you split up socket.js you can easily get rid of the circular dependency.

One solution could be a wrapper of `socket.io`:

```js
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const self = module.exports = {
  io: {},
  start: server => {
    self.io = socketIO(server)
  }
};
```

Once started, you are sure that `io` is initialized.